# Video Object not released by BoxLayout in a pop up

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

as stated in the title, I'm stuck when I try to show a BoxLayout which contains a video and two buttons - I have created an application which will take an input from user once user clicks on a button I'll show a pop-up which has a video and two buttons - Now the problem is first click it'll work fine but second time if i click it says the following error:

kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add kivy.uix.video.Video object at 0x0000000005C7EB40, it already has a parent kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x0000000005DB7B40

When I tried handling the exception but after that video plays in the background with the message Cannot add kivy.uix.video.Video object at 0x0000000005C7EB40, it already has a parent kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x0000000005DB7B40

```
from __future__ import print_function
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import WidgetException
import re, wmi


kv = """
<MainPage>:
    manager:screen_mgr
    do_default_tab: False
    textinputtext: waybill.text
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_mgr
        #transition: FadeTransition
        Screen:
            manager: screen_mgr
            id: intro
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            name: 'User'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    source: 'index.png'
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'center'
                anchor_y: 'center'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 20
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y': .8}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'left'
                        size_hint_x: .5
                        TextInput:
                            id: waybill
                            width: 20
                            text: root.textinputtext
                            multiline: False
                            height: self.minimum_height
                            size_hint_y: None
                            font_size: 30
                            focus: True
                            on_text: self.text
                            on_text_validate:app.on_waybill()
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            text: "Compare"
                            on_release: root.compareClicked()
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'right'
                anchor_y: 'bottom'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 50
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y': .8}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            id: statebtn
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            text: root.getusbdevices()
            AnchorLayout:
                anchor_x: 'left'
                anchor_y: 'top'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    size_hint: .5, .1
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1, 1, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    spacing: 50
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y': .5}
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'right'
                        size_hint_x: None
                        Button:
                            size_hint: None, None
                            height: 50
                            width: self.texture_size[0]
                            padding: 10, 10
                            on_release:root.current = root.switch_screen()
                            text: "Admin"
    TabbedPanelHeader:
        text: intro.name
        # store a screen name to link the tab to a screen
        screen: intro.name
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)
waybill = TextInput(text="Enter Waybill No.", multiline=False)
adwaybill = TextInput(text="Enter Waybill No.", multiline=False)
statebtn = Button(text="INSTRUMENT_NOT_FOUND")
player1 = Video(source='connect.mp4')
player2 = Video(source='place.mp4')
waybills = []

class MainPage(TabbedPanel):

    screen_mgr = ObjectProperty(None)
    textinputtext = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_text')
        self.textinputtext = "Enter Waybill No."

    def on_text(self):
        return self.textinputtext

    def on_text_validate(self):
        return self.textinputtext

    def on_focus(self, obj, focused):
        if not focused:
            self.dispatch('on_text_validate')

    def compareClicked(self):
        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar.value = 1
        print (self.on_text())
        if self.on_text()!='Enter Waybill No.' and self.getusbdevices() == u"CONNECTED":
            self.popup_1()

    def popup_1(self):
        self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=(10))
        self.box.add_widget(self.playPlace())
        popup = Popup(title='Warning: Please Place', title_size=(30),
                      title_align='center', content=self.box,
                      size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                      auto_dismiss=False)
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text="YES TO COMPARE", on_release=popup.dismiss))
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text="NO TO GO BACK", on_release=popup.dismiss))
        popup.bind()
        popup.open()

    def playConnect(self):
        player1.state = 'play'
        return player1

    def playPlace(self):
        player2.state = 'play'
        return player2

    def getusbdevices(self):
        c = wmi.WMI()
        statebtn.text = u"INSTRUMENT_NOT_FOUND"
        wql = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"
        for item in c.query(wql):
            if "USB Device" in item.Dependent.Caption:
                statebtn.text = u"CONNECTED"
            else:
                statebtn.text = u"INSTRUMENT_NOT_FOUND"
        return statebtn.text

    def switch_screen(self):
        self.manager.transition = FadeTransition()
        self.manager.current = self.manager.previous()
        return self.manager.current

    def switch_to(self, header):
        self.manager.current = header.screen
        self.current_tab.state = "normal"
        header.state = 'down'
        self._current_tab = header

class KartScanApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainPage()

    def on_waybill(self):
        waybill.bind(text=MainPage.on_text)
        return waybill.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    KartScanApp().run()
```

Above is the code, am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is the issue, Video object is not released as it is global,

So I moved these two declaration player1 = Video(source='connect.mp4') , player2 = Video(source='place.mp4') to their respective methods.